# Location object returning null in google maps android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am working on a project where the current latitude and longitude are taken from another class.When i switch off the phone or open the app the next day , the current latitude and longitude are shown as 0.0, which is because the location object is becoming null.But as soon as i open the app again the map is shown correctly.

The code in the main class:

```
public void getcurrentlocation()
{
    gps=new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
    if(gps.canGetLocation())
    {
        current_latitude=gps.getLatitude();
        current_longitude=gps.getLongitude();
        placemarkersonmap();
    }
    else
    {
    gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
}
public void placemarkersonmap()
{

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(current_latitude, current_longitude);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),current_latitude+" "+current_longitude,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12f));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12f));

    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(8.505439, 76.971293));


 googleMap.addMarker(marker);

}
```

The helper class for retrieving current latitude and longitude ,GPSTracker class:

```
package com.example.marinamapseg;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {


            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NO PROVIDER ENABLED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            0,
                            0, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                0,
                                0, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }      
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

I tried setting the minimum time between updates and the minimum distance between updates as 0 for the `requestLocationUpdates` method of `locationmanager` .But that didnt help either.

So the issue is why does the location object return null when i open the app the next day.It also works fine as soon as the close the app and restart it again.Please help!

Answer (score 0):

For getting updates make use of the `LocationListener` interface you have implemented instead of using

```
if (locationManager != null) {
    location = locationManager
                   .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
}
```

do the following in your `onLocationChanged()`

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
}
```

This makes sure that when a new location update is available it is stored in your respective variables.

PS: For getting location updates in the background, make sure that your service is not terminated when the app is closed. You could also make use of `SharedPreferences` if you want to persist changes even when the phone is restarted.

Comment: But the issue is that the location object itself is becoming null.

Comment: You are checking for `location != null` as it stands in your question. To get the location accurately, you need to make use of your`onLocationChanged()` otherwise it might return `null`.

Comment: And where is the `onStartCommand()` in your Service? Where are you making use of the `getLocation()` method? I don't see it being called anywhere.